# If a sequences of functions is not pointwise convergent then it has no subsequence that is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to show that $f_n(x)= \cos(nx)$ has not uniformly convergent subsequence.

$\cos(nx)$ isn't pointwise convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ so it seems that would me it can't have a subsequence which is uniform.

it is not pointwise because we can consider $\pi$ then we get   $f_n(\pi) = (-1)^n$

So in general can a sequence of functions ever be not-pointwise convergent yet have a uniform convergent subsequence?

Comment: Yes, trivially. Take $f_n(x) = (-1)^n$ as constant functions.

Comment: In general, pretty much anything that you would like to say of the form "if a sequence does ... then no subsequence does ..." is going to be difficult or impossible. You can start with a subsequence that does ... and then insert a bunch of bad terms to change the overall behavior.

Comment: @user296602 I didn't see your comment. Sorry.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, here is a more general example to illustrate the vague-and-not-to-be-taken-too-seriously principle that

> Pretty much anything that you would like to say of the form "if a sequence does ... then no subsequence does ..." is going to be difficult or impossible. You can start with a subsequence that does ... and then insert a bunch of bad terms to change the overall behavior.

Choose a uniformly convergent sequence $f_n$ with limit $f$, and any function $g \ne f$. Then the sequence
$$h_n = \left\{\begin{array}{cl} f_n & n \text{ even} \\ g & n \text{ odd}\end{array}\right.$$
is not pointwise convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f_n(x)=(-1)^n$$

This has atleast two uniformly convergent subsequences.

Comment: oh of course, the counterexample is right there

Comment: Of course, this even has uncountably many uniformly convergent subsequences,  not just two

Answer (score 0):

Hint for how you *can* show that $(f_n)$ has no uniformly convergent subsequence, for $f_n(t)=\cos(nt)$: If $n\ne m$ then $\int_0^{2\pi}|f_n-f_m|^2$ equals what? And now what does that say about $\sup_t|f_n(ft)-f_m(t)|$?